# Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions : SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When starting my app using firebase cloud messaging the app freezes on startup and I get the following message logged.

```
Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions : SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

This started happening after not receiving messages one day, then suddenly I got the message after maybe 2 min delay. I clicked the notification and the app crashed. Haven't been able to start the app since with above message.

Things I've tried.

1. Testing on several different real devices, they all get the same error.
2. Going back to a previously released app in google play console works, I can start the app fine, but
   trying to revert back to it in the current app in android studio doesn't work.

This is my current gradle dependencies :

```
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

I've tried to change the versions of the firebase bom, removing bom and only importing cloud messaging but nothing seems to work..

My theory is that the app crashed that day and whenever I start it it tries to send analytics or a bug report to firebase analytics or something, but fails when It can't create a new token... so I'ts stuck somehow...

Full log :

```
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: app id xxxx, app id xxx
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 43029
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: Faster debug mode event logging enabled. To disable, run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
E/FirebaseMessaging: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Won't retry the operation.
```

And yes I've tried to disable debug logging but it still fails to sync / generate the token

this is my snippet for token generation in my firebase messaging service

```
  override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Timber.d("Refreshed token: $token")
        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // FCM registration token to your app server.
        //sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    }
```

Any theories why the app freezes on startup? I've read all threads here and tried everything but nothing seems to work...

Comment: did you add internet permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes I have the internet permission in my manifest.

Comment: did you find any solution?